# Column-wise concatenating with every dataframe have different index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose we have a list of dataframes `A` which contains three dataframes `df_1`, `df_2`, and `df_3`:

```
A = [df_a, df_b, df_c]

df_a = 
                morning noon    night
date                
2019-12-31  B   3.0     3.0     0.0
            C   0.0     0.0     1.0
            D   0.0     1.0     0.0
            E   142.0   142.0   142.0

df_b = 
                morning noon    night
date                
2020-01-31  A   3.0     0.0     0.0
            B   1.0     0.0     0.0
            E   142.0   145.0   145.0

df_c = 
                morning noon    night
date                
2020-02-29  F   145.0   145.0   145.0
```

All dataframes have `morning`, `noon`, `night` columns and have same index which is `date` and `[A,B,C,D,E,F]` column and I want to concatenate those three dataframes into one dataframe (let's say `full_df`) which every `date` have equal rows/indexes.

But as you see each dataframe have different number of rows, `df_1`,`df_2`, and `df_3` have `[B,C,D,E]`, `[A,B,E]` and `[F]` respectively.

Is there some way we can concat those dataframes but this time, each dataframe have index of all unique index from those three combined ? It returns `0.0` if the corresponding index is not available on the original dataframe.

This is what I was thinking about `full_df`:

```
full_df =
                morning noon    night
date                
2019-12-31  A   0.0     0.0     0.0
            B   3.0     3.0     0.0
            C   0.0     0.0     1.0
            D   0.0     1.0     0.0
            E   142.0   142.0   142.0
            F   0.0     0.0     0.0
2020-01-31  A   3.0     0.0     0.0
            B   1.0     0.0     0.0
            C   0.0     0.0     0.0
            D   0.0     0.0     0.0
            E   142.0   145.0   145.0
            F   0.0     0.0     0.0             
2020-02-29  A   0.0     0.0     0.0
            B   0.0     0.0     0.0
            C   0.0     0.0     0.0
            D   0.0     0.0     0.0
            E   0.0     0.0     0.0
            F   145.0   145.0   145.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
pd.concat(A).unstack(level=-1, fill_value=0).stack()
```